# When I run a docker image it's stopped without giving any error?

Tags: python, django, docker, shell, dockerfile

There is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv /opt/venv

# Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Run the application:
EXPOSE 8000
COPY /myappp .
CMD ./script.sh
```

This is the **shell script**:

```
#!/bin/bash
source bin/activate
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

There is the output while image is running:
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rh9f.png)

As you see it's stopped there, after the model had train, but the container is kept starting.

I'm witing for output like this, to be able to use my api:
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpJWq.png)

**Note:** I don't know why nltk is dowloadning after the training, because in when i run the project from my host is the first thing, and the model can't train without ntlk.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: please provide these all in code

Comment: You shouldn't need your virtual environment in your when building your Docker image. You can change your `RUN` statement to just `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` and remove `source bin/activate` in your shell script. Maybe that will help ? If not, can you show your file structure, requirements.txt, build logs (when running `docker build`) ?